# Create button in Thunderbird 60+ plugin

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

So basically I am trying to create a really simple Thunderbird-Add-On with a button that opens a URL.

So I tried some of the Firefox-Example-Plugins (https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/tabs-tabs-tabs) but they all fail because of:

> Reading manifest: Error processing browser_action: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.

I could not find any documentation how Thunderbird 60+ differs from Firefox here and how to recreate browser_action for Thunderbird

Comment: AFAIK, Thundrbird doesn't support WebExtensions (or vice versa). One should use XUL etc.

Comment: [It does in beta (63)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird/Add-ons_Guide_63). It's just experimental and heavily [undocumented](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks @snipsnipsnip , that helped me to get the example plugin going. If you post an answer I can award you the bounty

Comment: I'll post. I was not sure but glad if that help :)

Comment: i think you should look into the source-code of this BrowseInTab (a TB addon) : https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/browseintab/?src=search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about your specific problem, but let me point to some resources that might help:

- [browser_action](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browserAction.html) API is available for Thunderbird 64+.
- [Read the Docs page](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is something closest to official documentation about Thunderbird WebExtension API. Surprisingly [MDN will not support Thunderbird.](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/2333#issuecomment-435333658)
- [Add-ons Update Guide 63+ on Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird/Add-ons_Guide_63) is getting updates (although it is focused on existing add-ons).
- [Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/c/thunderbird) was [once](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/discourse-vs-topicbox/50797/10) the official forum, but didn't gain much traction for add-on developers.
- [thunderbird.topicbox.com](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/addons/) is the proper and active community as of the end of 2019.

It is expected that you'll find some feature is missing in Thunderbird WebExtension API. Thunderbird developers are [extending WebExtension API](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/tb-planning/2018-December/006323.html) to match 'legacy' (i.e. current existing) add-on functionality. The plan is to wrap XPCOM feature in WebExtension flavor ("experiments") and call it migrated. They intend to aggregate proposals at [GitHub](https://github.com/thundernest/tb-web-ext-experiments).

**Edit 2019-03-02:** Thunderbird developer darktrojan added a nice tutorial on [add-on conversion](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to/extensions68.html) and [experiments development](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how-to/experiments.html). It says add-ons can include their own experiment declaration and implementation to use even in stable Thunderbird, so it looks like WebExtensions in Thunderbird can still use raw XPCOM Thunderbird API for now.

**Edit 2019-04-24:** The documentation is on [developer.thunderbird.net](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/upgrading-add-ons-for-tb68).

**Edit 2020-01-25:** Some quality conversations are on [thunderbird.topicbox.com](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/addons/).